# React - Error, Hookrouter invalid hook call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

can't handle this error any suggestions?

```js
import "./App.css";
import { navigate, useRoutes } from "hookrouter";

const routes = {
  "/": () => <h1>home</h1>,
  "/news": () => <h1>news</h1>,
};

function App() {
  const page = useRoutes(routes);
  return <div>{page || alert("not found")}</div>;
}

export default App;
```

this is app.js only this component exists nothing more then this also package.json and i think everything is okay but anyway returning invalid hook call but have no idea why

```json
{
  "name": "weather",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "@types/hookrouter": "^2.2.5",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install the package before using it!

use this command to install the package

```
npm i hookrouter

//or if you're using yarn try this:

yarn add hookrouter
```